# How to reducing impact on OLTP when performing ETL Process

Tags: sql-server, database, etl, data-warehouse

I am new in designing a ETL process. Currently I have two database, one is the live database where the application use it for every day transaction. The other one is the data warehouse.

I have a table in the live database that regularly have new data insert into it. The goal is that every night the ETL Process will transfer the data in the live database to the data warehouse, follow by deleting the data in the live database.

Due to my lack of knowledge, the solution that I got is to implement something call a rolling table. Basically on the live database, I have two tables that have the same structure. I call them *tblLive1* and *tblLive2*. I also has a synonym call *tblLive*. All insert is done on the synonym. The synonym would point at one of the table.

When I run the ETL process, I have a stored procedure that would drop and create a new synonym that point to *tblLive2*. This allow the ETL process to transform data from *tblLive1* without effecting the application.  The assumption is that the ETL Process takes an hour to run, and I won't want the ETL process lock the table preventing the application insert new data to it.

This solution should theoretically work, but not elegant.

I am sure this problem is a common problem, are there any other solutions out there?

Comment: What database are you using and what version of that database?  The answer is likely going to be highly database-dependent unless you really want the overhead of trying to come up with a database agnostic solution.

Comment: I am using SQL Server right now, but the concept will also apply to Oracle as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Bob's answer (above), It is usual in DWH/BI applications, that all necessary tables are essentially copied into a "staging" database or a "staging" schema on your DWH database(depending on the number of tables / size etc). These would ordinarily be on a different server to your OLTP system - for a DWH implementation of any size that is)

To answer the question on performance impact, it depends on your server spec/io configuration.

Is data being inserted into the OLTP system 24hours/day? or are there downtimes? or low traffic times?

It might be worthwhile using database compression as IO is going to be your biggest enemy and this will help considerably.

Comment: There is a low traffic time. So definitely this is the time we perform the ETL process. Thanks for the suggestion, I actually think it may worth to do a snapshot copy of the tables in OTLP db first, and then move them to the DWH, then perform Transformationon DWH.
Currently, the ETL process is designed such that the transformation is either done in C# application, or done in stored procedure. This stored procedure is stored in the DWH, but it dynamically access the OLTP and DWH to do the ETL.

Answer (score 1):

Read the table into a staging area and process the staging table. You usually want to spend as little time on the production system as you have too. Especially if it is in use.

You may also want to look into using tables loaded by a trigger. Or Change Data Capture if you are on SQL 2008

Comment: Yes, my goal is to spend as little time on the production system as possible to reduce the impact on the system.  For the staging table, is this some kind of temporary table? 
I am using SQL 2008. The tables that I needed to perform ETL ranges from 100k to 2000k of rows. Could tell if what are the performance impact would look like if my ETL process read read 100k + rows where identity number is less than a specific number while I insert 30+ row to the table every second concurrently.

Comment: Pulling 2 million rows into staging will only take a few minutes. I just pulled 1.5 million rows from a dev box through my laptop with 4GB RAM to a SQL 2008 dev box in under 4 minutes. All machines will be much slower then production. Update performance also depends on coding and performance tuning. But, you should be fine with your volume.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It may change our strategy on how we do ETL. I am assuming you use stored procedure to do the ETL, because it sounds very fast. 
We uses C#, which has a data access layer that are slowing the ETL process. The advantage of using C# app is we can do complicate transformation and easier to debug, but performance can be an issue.